# CSS3 rotateY direction firefox

Tags: css

First time posting here...

I have a problem with CSS3 rotateY()

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EstSiim/2sKZR/

Everything is working fine with Chrome, IE10 but in Firefox something strange is happening.
When you  click rotate- or rotate+ many times fast you can see that its not working correctly. (rotation direction changes)

Is it Firefox bug?

Tnx

HTML:

```
<div class="orange"></div>  
<input type="button" value="RotateY +" class="rotatey-plus">
<input type="button" value="RotateY -" class="rotatey-min">
```

CSS:

```
.orange {
    margin: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50% 100px;
    transform-origin:50% 50% 100px;

}
```

JS:

```
var positions = {
        ydeg:0,
        pers:400,
    };



    $('.rotatey-plus').on('click', function(){
        positions.ydeg += 90;
        rotate();
    });
    $('.rotatey-min').on('click', function(){
        positions.ydeg -= 90;
        rotate();
    });

    function rotate() {
        $('.orange').css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'perspective('+ positions.pers + 'px) rotateY(' + positions.ydeg + 'deg)',
             'transform': 'perspective('+ positions.pers + 'px) rotateY(' + positions.ydeg + 'deg)'
        });
    }
```

Comment: It looks like firefox is having an issue when you get around to 360 degrees. It rotates back around the long way. Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug that's happening only when you use the perspective function.

If you use the perspective property in a parent, it works ok:

```
<div class="container"><div class="orange"></div></div>

.container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}


function rotate() {
    $('.orange').css({
     'transform':  'rotateY(' + positions.ydeg + 'deg)'
    });
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sKZR/1/)